# Count Characters Function PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, strings, hash-map

As part of studying algorithms, I needed to make a function to count occurrences of characters in a string. My solution is below. I'd like some feedback about how I did - could the implementation be cleaner? Are there any conceptual gaps my code suggests?

```
<?php
function ra_count_chars($str){
    $dict = str_split(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $str)));

    foreach($dict as $key=>$value){
        $dict[$value] = 0;
        unset($dict[$key]);
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
        $dict[$str[$i]] += 1;
    }

    return $dict;
}

print_r(ra_count_chars('ccaaat'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with only one loop. I also find it easier to understand and to maintain if you have two variables instead of just one.  Unsetting the *numeric* keys while filling *associative* keys could get tricky at some point.

```
function ra_count_chars($str) {
    $dict = [];
    $chars = str_split(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $str)));

    foreach ($chars as $char) {
        isset($dict[$char]) ? ++$dict[$char] : $dict[$char] = 1;
    }

    return $dict;
}
```

It simply checks whether the character is already in the dictionary:

- if *no*, it's set
- if *yes*, its count is increased.

Keep in mind that this does not work for multi-byte characters.

---

<sup>Yes, this is PHP and so  this would work, too: `foreach ($chars as $char) { ++$dict[$char]; }`. But you should always check array values beforehand to not raise a `PHP: Notice`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a more reduced code, taking advantage of the PHP `count_chars()` function:

```
function ra_count_chars($str) {
    foreach (count_chars(str_replace(' ', '', $str), 1) as $char => $count) {
        $result[chr($char)] = $count;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This method has pros and cons:

- pro: the characters are alphabetically sorted in `$result`
- pro or con (depends on your need): upper- and lower-case are counted separately

In the other hand, as noticed by @insertusernamehere, this doesn't work for multibyte characters.

Last point: due to the above limitation, you might choose to omit not only spaces but also any character other than `A`-`Z` and `a`-`z`.
To achieve it merely change `str_replace(' ', '', $str)` into `preg_replace('/[^A-za-z]/', '', $str)`.

Comment: Today I learnt something. Didn't know that a function [`count_chars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) exists.